# Deploying Java J2ee application in weblogic 12c

Tags: weblogic

```
<BEA-101165> 
<Could not load user defined filter in web.xml: spark.servlet.SparkFilter.
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: 
Found interface org.objectweb.asm.MethodVisitor, but class was expected
```

I get this error when I deploy my application on weblogic 12c. Could you tell me how to fix this error?

Comment: Please post the error message.

Comment: <BEA-101165> <Could not load user defined filter in web.xml: spark.servlet.SparkFilter.
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.objectweb.asm.MethodVisitor, but class was expected


I get this error when I deploy my application on weblogic 12c. Could you tell me how to fix this error?

Comment: What is in your web.xml file? It sounds like you're literally referencing a Java interface instead of a proper class.

Comment: Are you doing FastSwap deployment?

Answer (score 0):

This error means that you are missing a library which has the actual implementation of the class org.objectweb.asm.MethodVisitor. If this is a 3rd party class then check if the appropriate jar is configured or not.  If this is your own implemention, then ensure that the implemention of this class is present in the classpath accessible to the war file.